# How to record GPS points without exceeding int256?

Tags: solidity, overflow

I want to record GPS points in my smart contract, and what I'm currently doing is removing the decimal. The problem is that some values exceed int256. How can I resolve this?

Comment: This is an interesting use case. Can you add more details about the values exceeding int256? Regular GPS coordinates shouldn't really be that big.

Comment: for exemple i have this coordinates: {latitude: 35.17380831799959, longitude: 2.8125}: after my conversion i have this: {latitude: 3517380831799959, longitude: 28125}. the value latitude exceed int256. Is there a way to avoid this, for example, a scaling system or splitting the latitude value into multiple variables? However, I want to be able to use the latitude and longitude values to calculate distances with other GPS points.

Comment: //57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819967
type(int256).max;

//-57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819968
type(int256).min;

Comment: You need to learn how to use fixed point math. There is a chapter in Solidity documentation.

Comment: yes you can add a scaling system, but that value does not exceed int256. This is the max int256 value you can have:

57896044618658097711785492504343953926634992332820282019728792003956564819967

Comment: A hacky way I saw to 'save' data on the blockchain is to use events to store the data you need. it can be an option!